# Does Padding widget provide extra facility which Container widget doesn't?

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

The `padding` property of `Padding` widget is also available in `Container` widget. Then what is the point of using `Padding` widget instead of `Container` widget? I found that `Padding` has `const` constructor which `Container` doesn't have. Is this the only reason of using `Padding` instead of `Container`?

Comment: AFAIK Container expands to accommodate the size of its parent. Padding only adds a surrounding padding without filling the parent. I may be wrong. Personally, I always use Container over Padding

Comment: @Sidak I also used to use `Container` instead of `Padding`. But I noticed `Padding` provides `const` constructor, while `Container` doesn't. So is this the reason to use `Padding` instead of `Container` if I don`t need to use other `Container` specific properties?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really any difference between the two. If you supply a `Container.padding` argument, `Container` simply builds a `Padding` widget for you.

Container doesn't implement its properties directly. Instead, Container combines a number of simpler widgets together into a convenient package. For example, the Container.padding property causes the container to build a Padding widget and the Container.decoration property causes the container to build a DecoratedBox widget. If you find Container convenient, feel free to use it. If not, feel free to build these simpler widgets in whatever combination meets your needs.

In fact, the majority of widgets in Flutter are simply combinations of other simpler widgets. Composition, rather than inheritance, is the primary mechanism for building up widgets.

[Source](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Padding-class.html).